# How can I send a Jquery var to be used in a CSS property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Need to know how I can use a Jquery var in a CSS property, I've searched around the net but haven't found any answers that refer to what I want, and also I'm not the greatest coder to figure this out. Have not used Jquery alot!

Code JQUERY:

```
 <script>
//find window height
          var winHeight = $(window).height(); 
          alert(winHeight);//=692
$('menuHolder').css(height(), winHeight);

 </script>
```

Comment: What does the function `height` return in `.css(height(), winHeight);` ? Have you actually read the [`.css` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) (I bet this would help you the most)? Also, as @Xander points out, in HTML there is no `menuHolder` element. Maybe you meant to use a class, or maybe you have to read some more [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) first. Btw there is nothing like a "jQuery variable". jQuery is a library and JavaScript is the language. If any, it's a JavaScript variable, but since we know that it's about JavaScript, it's just a variable ;)

Comment: `menuHolder` is an html element?!?! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues with your code:

1. `menuHolder` is not a valid html tag.
2. `height()` is a function call which I cannot imagine should ever return the string `"height"`.
3. It seems like you are not running this after the document is fully loaded?

Suppose your html looks like this:

```
<div id="menuHolder">This is the menu holder</div>
```

Note that the tag in question must have id attribute set to "menuHolder". If you have more than one menuHolder, then you should use the `class` attribute instead.

Then your js should be:

```
$(function(){
   $('#menuHolder').css("height", $(window).height());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/93hFW/

or

```
$(function(){
   $('#menuHolder').height($(window).height());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/93hFW/1/

If you have are using the `class` attribute instead as suggested above, then you should use a `.` (dot) instead of the `#` to prefix the jQuery selector.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, would i need to call that function or will it run automatically

Comment: @ScottRobertson The function is passed to jquery to be called once the DOM has fully loaded. Without this measure, jQuery may not be able to find the element, because it hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: Hey thanks alot for your reply, I was using a class: this worked perfectly! $('.menuHolder').css("height", $(window).height());

Comment: @ScottRobertson, your welcome. jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors. If your question is answered, you should accept it, by clicking the check mark. Doing so will mark this question as answered, award you 2 reputation points and 15 reputation points to the person who has answered your question.

Comment: That would be you @-d_inevitable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the height of the element?

```
$('menuHolder').css("height", winHeight);
```

would be better to do

```
$('menuHolder').height(winHeight);
```

Comment: Code is full of `<menuHolder />` elements for sure!